# Как определить номер записи выводимой из бд в цикле while

Tags: while, циклы, php

Здравствуйте, есть код

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
   print $post['title'];
}
```

Необходимо сделать как здесь

```
$x=0;
while($x++<5){
if($x==1){print "Первая запись, ";}else{print $x;}
}
```

т.е. определить первую запись

Comment: Ваш нужно по id в базе? или вообще первую запись?

Answer (score 1):

так?

```
$x = 1;
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
    if ($x == '1')
        echo 'первая запись';
    print $post['title'];
    $x++;
}
```

или так?

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
    if ($post['id'] == '1')
        echo 'запись c id 1';
    print $post['title'];
}
```

Comment: спасибо! первый вариант то, что нужно

Comment: я бы посоветовал сравнивать не со строкой, а с числом. Там, где уверены, что должно быть число, то приводить к числовому типу